# Connection between two dataframes created by dividing one dataframe in two

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I'm sorry if my title is confusing but I wasn't sure how to describe the situation that I'm currently trying to understand. But basically I stumbled upon this question when I was working with **train_test_split** procedure from sklearn module.

So, let's go ahead and I show you an example of what has been confusing me for couple of hours already.

Let's create a simple dataframe with 3 columns:

- 'Letter' - a letter from alphabet;
- 'Number' - serial number of the letter;
- 'Type' - type of the number.

```
    import pandas as pd
    data = [['A', 1, 'Odd'], ['B', 2, 'Even'], ['C', 3, 'Odd'],
    ['D', 4, 'Even'], ['E', 5, 'Odd'], ['F', 6, 'Even'], ['G', 7, 'Odd']]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Letter', 'Number', 'Type'])
```

We can create 4 samples to work with using train_test_split:

```
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    target = df['Type']
    features = df.drop('Type', axis=1)
    features_train, features_valid, target_train, target_valid = train_test_split(features,                                                                                  
                                                                 target, test_size=0.4, random_state=12)
```

And now if we want to see the rows of *features_train* with the odd numbers we can write the following code:

```
    features_odds = features_train[target_train == 'Odd']
    features_odds
```

And we get this:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txkMi.png)

And there we have it right as new dataframe contains the rows exactly with the odd numbers.
How does that work when *features_train* can get the info from *target_train* even though those are two separated dataframes?

I think there should be an easy answer but for some reason I'm not able to understand the mechanics of this right now.

I have also tried a different approach (not using **train_test_split**) but it works just as fine:

```
    target_dummy = df['Type']
    features_dummy = df.drop('Type', axis=1)
    
    features_dumb_odds = features_dummy[target_dummy == 'Odd']
    features_dumb_odds
```

Would appreciate and help in understanding it a lot!

Comment: Hey stn12, just to make sure I understand it correctly. Do you want to train/test-split both subframes, for odd and even numbers, respectively? Other than that the function sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split splits arrays/matrices/pandas dataframes *randomly* into train and test subsets. On the other hand, subsetting the pandas dataframe by column value (e.g. `odd`) is deterministic.

Comment: Hi, @7shoe. Not really, it's kind of random in terms of the type. I was just confused by the ability of features_train to address target_train with a specified parameter.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`target_train == 'Odd'` is a `Series` of boolean values. As a Series, it also has an index. That index is used to align with `features_train` that you index into, and it's compatible.

As a first step of exploration, start with `print(target_train == 'Odd')`

It's good to think about how the pieces fit together. In this case, the boolean series and where you index into need to have exactly the same index for it to not raise an exception.

Comment: Hi, @creanion! So if I had both **features_train** and **target_train** shuffled so their indexes wouldn't align anymore the answer wouldn't be correct?